# оставить в выборке результаты по сложному условию [%ColumnName2,3%], но именно для уникальных значений %ColumnName1%

Tags: sql, oracle

для такой таблицы

```
TABLE ANALYSIS_SAMPLES 
(
  ID NUMBER  NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY       --ключ
, HEAT VARCHAR2(15 BYTE) NOT NULL        --задача
, SAMPLE_NUMBER NUMBER(3, 0) NOT NULL    --№ образца
, SAMPLE_PLACE VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) NOT NULL --место взятия образца
)
```

например такого содержимого:

```
ID     HEAT      SAMPLE_NUMBER                    SAMPLE_PLACE  
5802   815804    3                                CCM1  
5801   815804    2                                CCM1  
0203   815804    1                                RH1  
5800   815804    1                                CCM1  
0204   825999    2                                LF3  
5781   826001    1                                CCM1  
0205   826001    1                                CON2  
5782   826001    2                                CCM1
```

необходимо оставить те только строки, у которых для каждой задачи `HEAT` место взятия образца `SAMPLE_PLACE`='CCM1' и имеет максимальный №образца `SAMPLE_NUMBER` внутри собственной нумерации для каждого значения `SAMPLE_PLACE`, т.е. ожидается что останутся из примера строки:

```
ID     HEAT      SAMPLE_NUMBER                    SAMPLE_PLACE  
5802   815804    3                                CCM1  
5782   826001    2                                CCM1
```

затруднение вызывает формулировка запроса, не идёт дальше

```
SELECT ID , HEAT, SAMPLE_NUMBER, SAMPLE_PLACE  
FROM PLANNING.ANALYSIS_SAMPLES PAS
WHERE SAMPLE_PLACE='ССМ1'
```

Как ограничить возвращаемый результат до максимального `SAMPLE_NUMBER` внутри собственной нумерации варианта значения `SAMPLE_PLACE` (только `SAMPLE_PLACE`='CCM1') для каждой уникальной задачи `HEAT` ??

Comment: Загнать запрос, для коего "не идёт дальше", в CTE, дополнив полем `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HEAT ORDER BY DESC) rn`, и снаружи отобрать `WHERE rn=1`.

Comment: Подобное работает для MySQL и PostgreSQL    
`SELECT ID , HEAT, SAMPLE_NUMBER, SAMPLE_PLACE FROM PLANNING.ANALYSIS_SAMPLES PAS WHERE SAMPLE_PLACE='ССМ1' AND SAMPLE_NUMBER  = (SELECT MAX(PAS2.SAMPLE_NUMBER ) FROM PLANNING.ANALYSIS_SAMPLES PAS2 WHERE PAS2.SAMPLE_PLACE='ССМ1')`

Comment: @ShokhrukhIsmoilov *Подобное работает* В общем случае ни разу не работает. Во всяком случае, таким запросом ну никак не получить на выходе те две записи, что показаны в вопросе. Даже после исправления опечатки (в первой из записей SAMPLE_NUMBER должен быть равен трём).

Comment: Вот это место непонятно: "у которых для каждой задачи HEAT место взятия образца SAMPLE_PLACE='CCM1' и имеет максимальный №образца SAMPLE_NUMBER внутри собственной нумерации". Что если максимальному номеру образца соответствует не `CCM1`, а другое место? Брать максимум для `CCM1`? Не брать ничего?

Comment: @Akina  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HEAT ORDER BY **SAMPLE_NUMBER** DESC) rn, действительно, спс.

Comment: @Dmitry у каждого места взятия образца `SAMPLE_PLACE` своя нумерация в поле `SAMPLE_NUMBER `;  интересует только `SAMPLE_PLACE`='CCM1' -- прочие игнорируем